# serverless-s3-local writing to real S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless-framework-offline

I am using Serverless framework with the [serverless-s3-local](https://github.com/ar90n/serverless-s3-local) plugin to test my code during development. However, despite being in offline mode, the real S3 bucket is being written to. How can I alter my configuration to use a local fake s3 bucket when in offline mode?

**Relevant serverless.yml sections:**

```
plugins:
  - serverless-stack-output
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
  - serverless-layers
  - serverless-deployment-bucket
  - serverless-s3-local
  - serverless-offline
custom:
  #...
  s3:
    bucketName: test-s3-buck
    host: localhost
  serverless-offline:
    ignoreJWTSignature: true
    httpPort: 4000
    noAuth: true
    directory: /tmp
resources:
  Resources:
    #...
    Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.s3.bucketName}
```

**Endpoint Calling S3:**

```
import boto3


def post(event, context):
    s3_path = "/test.txt"
    body = "test"
    encoded_string = body.encode("utf-8")

    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    bucket_name = "test-s3-buck"
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=encoded_string)

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "Created."
    }
    return response
```

**Launching Serverless Offline:**

```
serverless offline start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the readme file in [serverless-s3-local](https://github.com/ar90n/serverless-s3-local) we have:

```js
  const S3 = new AWS.S3({
    s3ForcePathStyle: true,
    accessKeyId: 'S3RVER', // This specific key is required when working offline
    secretAccessKey: 'S3RVER',
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:4569'),
  });
```

you can achieve [the same with](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#passing-credentials-as-parameters) `boto`:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='S3RVER',
    aws_secret_access_key='S3RVER'
)
```

which means, when you run your `serverless offline start` you need to set the aws access key id to `S3RVER` and aws secret access key to `S3RVER`, otherwise, the real bucket will be used.

also in the readme, there's instructions to setup a `s3local` aws profile, https://github.com/ar90n/serverless-s3-local#triggering-aws-events-offline

another way to achieve it is to run your command with environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=S3RVER AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=S3RVER serverless offline start
```

in that way, the aws-sdk inside your code will read the correct values for the offline mode